# Flume batch size

Tags: flume

My flume config is

```
agent.sinks.sink.batchSize=10
```

which flume process `10 reacords at each batch`,I get same time for all records.

so, it is possible way to get distinct time for each record in batch.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [timestamp interceptor](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#timestamp-interceptor) for setting timestamps?

Let's take a look at its [source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=blob;f=flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/interceptor/TimestampInterceptor.java;h=9d942f6ba02b10ad100303c8de158f0b49fcc002;hb=trunk):

```
  /**
   * Modifies events in-place.
   */
  @Override
  public Event intercept(Event event) {
    Map<String, String> headers = event.getHeaders();
    if (preserveExisting && headers.containsKey(TIMESTAMP)) {
      // we must preserve the existing timestamp
    } else {
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      headers.put(TIMESTAMP, Long.toString(now));
    }
    return event;
  }

  /**
   * Delegates to {@link #intercept(Event)} in a loop.
   * @param events
   * @return
   */
  @Override
  public List<Event> intercept(List<Event> events) {
    for (Event event : events) {
      intercept(event);
    }
    return events;
  }
```

I suppose that execution time of `intercept(List<Event> events)` method is so small that all events in batch are processed within one millisecond. So, it is not possible to force different timestamps for events in batch using this interceptor.

If you need unique identifier for each event in batch, you can write your own interceptor based on TimestampInterceptor code, that will append number of event in batch to timestamp. However, it will no guaranteee global uniqueness of intentifiers, because it is possible that two batches will be processed within one millisecond.

For more concrete advice clarify your requirements, please.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to get the timestamp for the events correct - either by setting the timestamp header at generation time or by parsing the string and setting the timestamp that way.